# mongoose _id field not a string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a mongoose model object Task. 
It is a simple crud model. When user create a task, I save a new one and return with

```
res.json(task)
```

When user update the task, I pass the _id field, which is

`"54c745eedab1ca036058d4fb"`

Then I loop through all the tasks (which are object query results), and check if each task has the same _id field. But I get this as the _id:

```
"TÇEîÚ±Ê`XÔû"
```

I think it maybe binary code or something. I don't use unicode for my website. 
So what maybe wrong and how should I solve it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think  Task.findById(_id)  should work

Comment: you mean findById(54c745eedab1ca036058d4fb) or "TÇEîÚ±Ê`XÔû"

Comment: findById(54c745eedab1ca036058d4fb, function(err, task) {